# Unknown postgis gps data format

Tags: gps, postgis

A third-party program stores tracking data to the db, but I not understand the format. I know that `postgis` is working there and this column should contain `GPS` location(s) and maybe additional data.

Example (db dump as csv):

```
"Location","DateTime"
"010100000023E37C4023E33C40417F41EF407F4740","2020-05-24 15:33:53+00"
```

How can I decode Location column data?

Comment: You should mention the program, so we may have some idea. But probably we cannot get a result. You should try to put simple coordinates on the program and check the output, until you understand the format. I I would check. It seems hex numbers. first 10 characters (5 bytes): a header. then two numbers of 16 bytes. Try getting them as integer or as half float. And compare with expected coordinates. And try again and again until you get an idea. If you can inject data: try with 0,0, and then go east and then west, and then north, and then south. Then you should have an idea

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thanks, I think I figured it out, it's [Well-known binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry#Well-known_binary) format.

Comment: You should write an answer. It is allowed by the site. This can help other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Well-known binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry#Well-known_binary) format.

See `PostGIS` methods for `WKB`: [ST_AsBinary](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsBinary.html), [ST_GeomFromWKB](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromWKB.html).
`WKT` methods: [ST_AsText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html), [ST_GeomFromText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html).

The example in `WKT` format: `POINT(28.887256651392033 46.99416914651966)`.

For `.Net` can use [Geo](https://github.com/sibartlett/Geo), [NetTopologySuite.IO.TinyWKB](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.TinyWKB).